# Fastboot not working on macOS High Sierra 10.13

Tags: macos-sierra, fastboot

Am trying to root an android device and for that I need to run ADB & Fastboot command.

Issue is that, fastboot command is giving an error and it just doesn't make any sense to me. After googling, only suggestion which I found was to update the Android SDK, which I have already done but it didn't solve the issue.

```
XXX-MacBook-Pro:Documents driftking9987$ fastboot devices
ERROR: Unable to create a plug-in (e00002be)
```

Answer (score 2):

THere's an open issue with macOs High Sierra. There hasn't been a release of a known working version, but you can download it from the issue tracker itself and I just tests that it works:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64292422#comment8

Comment: Note that once you download it, you must also make the file executable chmod +x and run it as a bash script ./fastboot

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest SDK platform-tools worked for me:

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html